# Animate a slide-in details view within a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

I have a `UITableViewCell` that is using auto-layout. When a user selects the cell, I want to display extra information in a details view that slides downwards, extending the bottom of the cell.

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way to do this.

The `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` method does not seem appropriate, because I am not replacing one view with another.

The `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` method seemed like it should do the trick, but I can't figure out the correct way to achieve my goals using it.

This is what I tried initially (C#, but Objective-C/Swift equivalents should be obvious):

```
private void AnimateDetailsIntoView()
{
    this.detailsView.Hidden = true;

    this.ContentView.ConstrainLayout(() =>
        this.detailsView.Top() == this.nameLabel.Bottom() &&
        this.detailsView.Bottom() == this.ContentView.Bottom() - Layout.StandardSiblingViewSpacing &&
        this.detailsView.Left() == this.nameLabel.Left() &&
        this.detailsView.Right() == this.nameLabel.Right());

    this.AddSubview(this.detailsView);

    UIView.Transition(
        this,
        0.2,
        UIViewAnimationOptions.ShowHideTransitionViews | UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromBottom,
        () => { },
        () => { });
}
```

This results in the table cell "spinning around", but the details view does not actually show. Even if I remove the line that hides `detailsView`, I still don't see it after the animation.

I suspect this is layout related, but am unsure how to "grow" the cell vertically.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

PS. I realize there's more to do once I get the initial animation working. I'll have to animate any previously selected cell up and remove its details panel.

Comment: did u mean you want to expand a uitableview cell ?

Comment: @Vizllx: yes. When the user selects the cell, it expands downwards to show the details.

Answer (score 0):

As per the OP wants to expand and collapse the cell, following are the procedure to achieve it:-

1. Design your whole detail cell in a single prototype cell.
2. Now `tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:` specify 2 sizes one for collapse cell and another size for (expanded)detailed cell,by giving a condition something like BOOL variable"isExpanded".
3. Now on `didSelect` of tableView or in the button's action  if you are using button in cell, just store the value of indexpath.row to determine which row to expand and add this code to reload the row, this will easily do the animation trick of expand

[tbl beginUpdates];

[tbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

[tbl endUpdates];

4. Same goes for collapsing a cell, just some logic tweaks, which you can easily do.

Comment: This isn't working for me because calling reload in `didSelect` prevents `didDeselect` from running. Therefore, I can't reverse the effect and previously selected rows remain selected.